# This is giving inaccurate results for inputs

Tags: c++, c++11

Program for finding factorial of a number is providing inaccurate output for the input >20.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    unsigned int i,p;
    unsigned long int f=1;
    cout<<"Enter Number  : "<<endl;
    cin>>i;
    for (p=i;p>1;p-=2){
        f=f*p*(p-1);
    }
    cout<<"Factorial is \n"<<f;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you building for a 32-bit system? `long` isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits, and on some systems with some compilers is only 32 bits.

Comment: Even if `long` is 64 bits `f*p*(p-1);` can overflow at 32 bits, because `p` is 32 bits. The compiler may evaluate `p*(p-1)` first. In general don't assume left to right evaluation order.

Comment: Your loop looks like a very pointless "optimization". Even with a wider type, you will overflow long before it makes any possible measurable difference compared to the "obvious" code.

Answer (score 0):

20! is 2.43*10^18 which is a lot greater than unsigned long int.